# Файл замещения renderfield.php как заставить работать?

Tags: joomla, joomla3

В чистой, только что установленной `Joomla 3.6.5` в компоненте `com_contact`
имеется файл замещения по такому пути:

```
\components\com_contact\layouts\joomla\form\renderfield.php
```

Данный файл предназначен для изменения логики работы отрисовки полей в форме создаваемой на основе `XML`.

По логике системы замещений в `Joomla`, этот файл должен работать и для другого компонента если его разместить по соответствующему пути. Например

```
\components\com_users\layouts\joomla\form\renderfield.php
```

Но сколько бы я не бился, не менял разные пути для расположения файла замещения, например в каталог шаблона, этот файл не подхватывается системой.

Баг или чего то нехватает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема состоит в том что это 'новшество' работает пока только для компонента `com_contact`, в других компонентах оно не будет работать т.к для `Joomla` ядра, файл `renderfield.php` который находится например  в `\components\com_users\layouts\joomla\form\`  - неизвестен и ядро не знает что с ним делать.

Comment: Тогда я не понял, почему этот например чел написал такое. https://coderwall.com/p/gufezw/override-joomla-core-layouts-in-your-custom-component-j-3-4-x

Comment: Некоторое время назад я пробовал использовать renderfield.php в своём компоненте, однако результатов не было, я перелопатил почти весь фреймворк и исходя из цепочки кодовых вызовов я думаю что диагноз именно в том что renderfield.php не понятен для моего компонента.

Comment: я просмотрел ссылку  coderwall.com/p/gufezw . он делал на joomla 3.4, не знаю данный метод насколько работоспособен на 3.6.5

Comment: А вы не нашли случайно то место где в ядре прошито чтобы он понимал com_contact? На данном этапе я готов на правку ядра чтобы оно заработало, а потом пофиксят и обновлю. Тем более проект в репе и все отслеживается.

Comment: я не заметил кода где конкретно вбивается именно com_contact, возможно такого и не будет, в этом и загвоздка, вся логика renderfild должна быть именно в root/layouts/joomla/form/renderfilds  но конкретного совета что можно подпилить, затрудняюсь дать , сам лично не нашёл ничего путного

Answer (score -1):

Конкретно этот файл переопределите, если положите в `\yourtemplate\layouts\com_users\joomla\form\`